# Were the bullet holes already in the wall?

Tags: pulp-fiction

In *Pulp Fiction*, the bullet holes seem to already be in the wall before the dude who looks like *Jerry Seinfeld* shoots at Jules and Vincent, was this a mistake?

At 1:08 you can clearly see the bullet holes,

Then at 1:39 the same holes are still there.

### So was this a mistake?

Comment: You can clearly see that the holes were there before Seinfeld tried to kill them, and then *one* additional hole appears between SLJ and Travolta.  I'd say it was a production/continuity mistake, unless we're supposed to believe he pumped all 6 bullets into that single new hole.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes, this is a mistake.**

Saw the video below as a suggestion after the one you linked for what to watch next.  #7 on the list calls out the bullet holes as a production error.  They seem to have done their research on the explanations for each point they raise, so had those holes been there "on purpose" I imagine they would have mentioned why.  (Spoiler alert: they don't.)

Also, just FYI, that guy is not Jerry Seinfeld.  His (her) name was Robert Arquette (credited on IMDB as [Alexis Arquette](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000793/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t43), as she apparently had gender reassignment surgery at some point after this movie was filmed.)